# How to use Blob.toPDF() method to create attachment body containing image and texts

Tags: apex, attachment, encodingutil, blob.topdf

I want to use Blob.toPDF() method to create attachment body, currently using:

```
attachmentPDF.Name = account.Name + '.pdf';
 attachmentPDF.body = Blob.toPDF(pdfContent);`
```

Inside `pdfContent` I want to incorporate image and some text in this way `pdfContent=EncodingUtil.base64Decode(call.Signature__c)` and some text fileds too `pdfContent=pdfContent+ call.Account__c`. Please suggest some technical solutions using the  Blob.toPDF() method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blob.toPDF() should work with a simple HTML input string. So you might do something like the following (untested):

```
<html><body><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,dGVzdA==" /><p>Additional Content</body></html>
```

Please be aware, that Blob.toPDF() has always been very buggy in the interpretaion of the HTML, that you may throw on it. But i don't know if that does hold true for API 31.

Comment: Hi Alexander, i've tried this out, throwing me some error 'Review all error messages below to correct your data.
An error occurred while parsing the input string.' please suggest. I've used  pdfContent= pdfContent + FORM_HTML_START ;
        pdfContent ='<img src=\"data:image/jpeg;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAApAAAACQgAAEIQAACAxH4tk54VvKzMTEIQAACEGiBwH8BsgK34VJMUqcAAAAASUVORK5CYII=\"/>';
pdfContent= pdfContent+FORM_HTML_END ;

Answer (score 0):

Now that time has passed a bit...

I'm trying to use a trigger generate a custom PDF and attach it to an email.  Since PageReference.getContent() is not trigger-friendly, I'm using blob.toPDF().  It's working perfectly - except for choking on the image I'd like to include.

So...any more thoughts on the topic?

Thanks